# can not stop docker container , permission denied error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have a docker file like this which runs a *hello-world* FastAPI app.

```
FROM python:3.10.9-alpine3.16
RUN adduser -D app
USER app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirement.txt

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

I am running docker build and docker run command as :

```
docker build mytag/fastapi_web_app:latest .
docker run -p 8080:8080 mytag/fastapi_web_app:latest
```

and app works fine , but docker stop does not work on it,
whenever i try docker stop i get permission denied error, I even added my user to a new *docker* group as well , *even if i repeat above step as a root user it does not work.*
I am running **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS** a a virtual machine on windows.

I had to sh into the machine using **docker exec** command and then kill the process to stop the docker container , but this is not the right solution.
I should be able to stop docker container using *docker stop* command, even **docker compose down** does not work.

when I run docker stop  this is the error I get:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: <id>: permission denied
```

What am I missing here?

P.S. : Do not ask me to **kill apparmor** , i have other processes dependent on it and its just a workaround not a solution

Comment: Can you show the exact error you get when you do `docker stop` or `docker compose down`?

Comment: just permission denied , i added that in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker kill --signal=SIGTERM container_id`

This should enable you to terminate the process that is currently running within the container and terminate the container using the `docker stop` command.